# Download file from google drive api to my server using php

Tags: php, curl, google-drive-api, google-picker

1 - I have configure google picker and it is working fine and I select the file from picker and get the file id.

2 - After refresh token etc all process I get the file metadata and get the file export link

```
$downloadExpLink = $file->getExportLinks();
 $downloadUrl = $downloadExpLink['application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'];
```

3 - After that I use this

```
if ($downloadUrl) {
     $request = new Google_HttpRequest($downloadUrl, 'GET', null, null);

        $httpRequest = Google_Client::$io->authenticatedRequest($request);
        if ($httpRequest->getResponseHttpCode() == 200) 
        {
            $content = $httpRequest->getResponseBody();
             print_r($content);


        } else {
        // An error occurred.
         return null;
     }
```

and get this response

```
 [responseBody:protected] => PK��DdocProps/app.xml���
�0D���k�I[ѫ��m
��!����A={���}�
2G�Z�g�V��Bľ֧�n�Ҋ�ap!����fb�d����k}Ikc�_`t<+�(�NJ̽�����#��EU-
�0@���P����........
```

4 - I use some cURL functions to get file from google drive and save it to server. IN server directory a file created but cropped. I use this code

```
$downloadExpLink = $file->getExportLinks();
$downloadUrl = $downloadExpLink['application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'];

//$downloadUrl value is
/*https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=1CEt1ya5kKLtgK************IJjDEY5BdfaGI&exportFormat=docx*/
```

When I put this url into browser it will download file successfully but when I use this url to fetch file with cURL or any php code and try to save it on server it saves corrupted file.

```
$ch = curl_init();
$source = $downloadUrl;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $source);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

$destination = "test/afile5.docx";
$file = fopen($destination, "w+");
fputs($file, $data);
fclose($file);
```

It result a corrupted file stored on server but whe I use this code to get any file other then google drive I download it successfully on server.

Can any one please help that how to download file from $downloadUrl to my server using php ?

Comment: Did you check any file or memory size contrains in your php, suhosin or curl configurations?

Comment: I have some sort of related issues but what you are getting back is the binary data / raw files data. It's not a corrupted file but an unformatted file

Comment: Did you find an answer ? I have the same problem